# Android Json application error

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to create an android login application using Json with MySQL Data Base but when I run it and try to login, I get the following error :

```
11-22 12:29:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(731): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-22 12:29:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(731): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-22 12:29:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:101)
11-22 12:29:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at com.example.loctrans.DBConnection.DBConnection(DBConnection.java:41)
11-22 12:29:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at com.example.loctrans.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:56)
11-22 12:29:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
11-22 12:29:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
11-22 12:29:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-22 12:29:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-22 12:29:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-22 12:29:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-22 12:29:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-22 12:29:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-22 12:29:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-22 12:29:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-22 12:29:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

when I was verifying the code, I added a log.e() method to find the line with error. here is my BD connection code

```
public class DBConnection extends Activity{
String result =  null;
    InputStream is = null;

public String DBConnection(ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs, String URL){

      try{
          Log.e("info error", " fase 2");
          HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
          Log.e("info error", " fase 3");
          HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
          Log.e("info error", " fase 4");
          httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
          Log.e("info error", httppost.toString());
          HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
          Log.e("info error", " fase 6");
          HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
          Log.e("info error", " fase 7");
          is = entity.getContent();
          Log.e("info error", " fase 8");
  }catch(Exception e){
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in http connection"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
  //convert response to string
  try{
      Log.e("info error", " fase 9");
          BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          Log.e("info error", " fase 10");
          String line = null;
          while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                  sb.append(line + "\n");
          }
          is.close();
          result=sb.toString();
          Log.e("log_tag", "Cadena JSon " + result);
  }catch(Exception e){
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error converting result "+e.toString(), 
              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
  }
  return result;
}

public String getResult(){
    return result;
}

}
```

In the logcat only there are the first three log.e message.

```
11-22 12:29:07.899: E/info error(731):  fase 2
11-22 12:29:07.919: E/info error(731):  fase 3
11-22 12:29:07.929: E/info error(731):  fase 4
```

so I think the problem is at this line : 
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs)
but I don't know what is the error exactly

Here is a part of Main Activity code :

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Login" ,logi));
String URL = "http://192.168.1.10/Android/getlogin.php";          
DBConnection DBC = new DBConnection();
String result = DBC.DBConnection(nameValuePairs, URL);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:101)
  at com.example.loctrans.DBConnection.DBConnection(DBConnection.java:41)
```

The LogCat reports the problem is with `getApplicationContext()` in your Toast, but this in in the catch block. You are right the *real* problem is with your Http code, it is probably throwing a NetworkOnMainThread exception. (Are you using Android 3.0+?)

You need to execute potentially slow network operations in a different thread. Simply create a custom AsyncTask and move your code into `doInBackground()`.

---

Why does DBConnection extend Activity? Are you using it like an Activity in code that you haven't posted?

Comment: thanks for your help i'm trying to use AsyncTask
i'm using Android 4.1
for the DBConnection is only used in the code that I have posted, so i don't have to extend it from Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Inside an Activity you should to use the keyword **this** where you to need a context and not getApplicationContext().

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Error in http connection"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

This error refers to this, and, like Sam says, there are a problem related to your HTTP code running inside a Thread UI. You need to use a AsyncTask to do all your HTTP job.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Using `this` won't work either. The Toast is being called in the Activity's constructor, not `onCreate()` method and the Activity is being started with `new DBConnection()`... There are quite a few things wrong with the sara's current approach.

Comment: I'm confused because the method don't like a constructor...

  public String DBConnection ...

Comment: Good catch, it is a method. This is a horrible practice: method names should start with a lowercase letter and shouldn't share the same name as the class...